# handling packet listeners in xmpp

Tags: android, android-listview, xmpp, android-adapter

I am trying to develop a android chat application using asmack api and server is openfire.
I am at the stage of handling incoming messages from users and representing them corresponding user chat screen (i.e. activity).

So for that, I developed 2 activities i.e.

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity 
public class UserActivity extends Activity
```

resultactivity is the one which maintains roster presence information like online , away etc. so this would be only one instance.

useractivity is the one which maintain chat list with the corresponding user. This activity starts with onclick event on list in ResultActivity. so this can be more than one based on no of users on Result activity..

So to listen to incoming packets (i.e. incoming messages) I added a listener in the ResultActivity which adds messages into global arraylist.

In Result Activity:

```
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
MainActivity.connection.addPacketListener(receive_message, filter);

PacketListener receive_message = new PacketListener() {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        message = (Message) packet;
        String sender=null,body=null,sender_final=null;
        if (message.getBody() !=null) {
            Log.d("UA", "message from "+StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom()));
            Log.d("UA", "message is "+message.getBody());
            sender = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
            sender_final=sender.substring(0, sender.indexOf('@'));
            body = message.getBody();

            Log.d("UA", "Sender : "+sender_final+" body : "+body);
            userMessage = new UserMessage("In", sender_final, body);
            userMessage_list.add(userMessage);

            userMessage_list.add(userMessage);

        }
    }
};
```

After adding the message in the global message list (i.e. userMessage_list) I need to update the user activity with incoming message. userMessage_list is the array list used as array in the getview method of base adapter extended class.

So Now I need the update the userActivity list with notifydatasetchanged method.

In UserActivity :

```
private class UserActivityThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
    UserActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So how to call the notifydatasetchanged method in the another activity.

I am curious to know how this scenario is handled in whatsapp or any chat applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem in my chat app by using a `ContentProvider` class and a `CursorLoader`which will be automatically notified everytime certain URI has new records.

In your case I would recommend you launching a broadcast message. Your class which has a `ListView` with the messages will have registered a `BroadcastReceiver` and it will be listening to possible updates. Everytime your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` is triggered in your activity, refresh your adapter.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

How to achieve this:

1. Create a `BroadcastReceiver` object in your activity.

   `BroadcastReceiver mReceiver`;
2. Code your broadcast receiver (on your onCreate for example)

   ```
       mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //extract our message from intent
           String extra= intent.getStringExtra("extra");

           Log.i("msg received: ", extra);

       }
   };
   ```
3. Add `IntentFilter` (in your onResume could be valid)

   `IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.myproject.myintentfilter");`

4.1 register your receiver

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);
}
```

4.2 Unregister your receiver

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

5. Make sure your receiver will receive the message, cheking that your `sendBroadcast` matches the `IntentFilter`.

Finally:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.myproject.myintentfilter").putExtra("extra", "This is a new value");
this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

**EDIT 2**

In the case of receiving a message during your activity rotation (receiver is not registered) I have found 2 solutions which I am not very satisfied with, but they work.

1. Reload your listview after orientation change, as the activity destroys itself, you can just reload the information of your listview, your new message should appear anyway.
2. Put a static field in your activity, everytime you receive a message, put such variable to TRUE. If your broadcastReceiver triggers, put that variable to false, and when your `onResume / onCreate` method is called after a change of orientation, check your static variable and do your reload if the variable was true (put it to false after reloading the ListView).

Comment: I tried. but the activity which is having listview of messages was already extend with Activity and corresponding adapter class also extended with baseadapter. I tried with inner class extending the broadcast receiver but it was not recognised in manifest.. I mean in runtime it is throwing class which extended broadcast reciever was not identified..

Comment: @kavuru check now if this helps you

Comment: I implemented successfully. got one query while writing.. How about notification come in the gap of unregister and register receiver. Do they get notified after registering again?